# How to remove default title in selectpicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement [angular selectpicker](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select).

The thing is when you go like this

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

everything's displayed good and you can see that selectpicker has a title of the first option.

But as soon as I added **ng-model** directive, It started having "Nothing selected" title that's completely unsuitable for me.

So how can I fix this?

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="selectDemoApp">

<body>
  <div role="main">
    <div class="container">
      <section ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
        <div class="page-header">

          <select class="selectpicker" ng-model="changeState" ng-change="go(changeState)">
            <option value="https://google.com">Mustard</a>
            </option>
            <option value="/2.html">Ketchup</a> 
            </option>
            <option value="/3.html">Relish</a>

          </select> 
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('selectDemoApp', [ 'angular-bootstrap-select', 'angular-bootstrap-select.extra']);

function SelectCtrl($scope, $location) {

  $scope.go = function ( path ) {
    alert(path)
};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert option:

```
<option style="display:none" value="">select...</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `ng-init` to initialize the value for the select field. Something like this `ng-init="changeState='https://google.com'`

Comment: Good answer, but I think mblenton provided more neat solution.